# Django join tables with ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, join, django-models

I'm trying to join 3 tables with ForeignKey but it returns Null values. I'm using select related and also I tried Insight.objects.all() but both are not working.

Here are my models:

```
class schedule(models.Model):
    login_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20)
    agent_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class place_no(models.Model):
    place_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,     null=True)
    pc_no =  models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class Insight(models.Model):
    login_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20)
    place_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    agent_name = models.ForeignKey(
        schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    pc_no = models.ForeignKey(
        place_no, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True
    )
```

My View:

```
def listings(request):
data = Insight.objects.select_related('agent_name', 'pc_no')

return render(request, 'pages/listings.html', {'data':data})
```

```html
{% for item in data %}
<tr>
<td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.login_id }}</td>
<td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.place_id }}</td>
<td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.agent_name.agent_name }}</td>
<td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.pc_no.pc_no }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How are you creating Insights and assigning agent_name, pc_no. The tables have the relationship but you still need to enter the schedule and place_no objects somehow or they will be null (which your definition allows)

Comment: That's my problem I don't know can I enter that values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by the below, I could update the DB with the result of the below query

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
    UPDATE Insight
        SET agent = ( SELECT agent_name FROM schedule
            WHERE Insight.login_id = schedule.login_id ) ''')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not valid. I can see, that you are thinking, that there is connection between tables with ForeignKey. Actually, there might be connection between Objects, not between whole tables.

You should not name classes with snake_case. Always use CamelCase.

To have any relation by `ForeignKey` you have to set it during creation or afterwards:

```
s = schedule.objects.create(login_id="Some login", agent_name=...)
p = place_no.objects.create(place_id="Place id", pc_no=...)
```

Then you can create `Insight` object that will be related to them:

```
i = Insight.objects.create(agent_name=s, pc_no=p, ...)
```

Then in your view/template there should be access to related objects.
PS. For early experiences with Django i recommend using `Model.objects.all()` or `Model.objects.filter(...)` instead of `Model.objects.select_related(...)`. You can better learn and understand that way. It will be time for improvements later.

I can recommend reading [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my case I'm getting the data from customer input by uploading CSV files so if you could help what should I do to join the tables and update them with the related values.